# Understanding the fork system call in UNIX

Tags: c, linux, unix, process, fork

I'm trying to understand both the execution order of a line of code given to me earlier and process creation using the `fork()` system call. It's in C language for running on UNIX.

I understand the main concept behind `fork()`, nevertheless, I want to understand the process tree creation derived from the following line of code:

```
x = fork() || !fork();
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You know what `fork()` returns? You know about short circuit evaluation? Add those together and you should end up with 3 processes...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The initial parent-process who runs the code (let's say its is `PID = 1000`), executes the `x = fork()` part, and spawns a new child-process (let's say `PID = 1001`).

For process `PID = 1000`, the value of the logical expression so far is non-zero, because [`fork(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork) returns its child's `pid`. Thus, due to [short circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation#Support_in_common_programming_languages), the rest part of the logical expression isn't evaluated as it's not needed.

For process `PID = 1001`, the value of the logical expression so far is `0`, because in the case of the new process created, [`fork(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork) returns `0`; so it has to evaluate the rest part of the logical expression too. It executes the `!fork()` part, spawning a new process (let's say `PID = 1002`).

The process tree derived is the following:

```
       1000
        |
        |
       1001
        |
        |
       1002
```

Answer (score 1):

[chrk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25478306/3755692) is great, in addition, `fork()` return 2 times, one is pid of child process in parent process, the other is 0 returned from child process. Both processes continue to process   after `fork()` returns.